# Keychain Prompt - Save To Keychain Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to implement Keychain from start to finish for my Xamarin Application. At the moment I have the initial bit that will display the **native prompt** `Touch ID to Use Password'. That works successfully using the bit of code below.

```
public class TouchId : ITouchID
{
    public Task<bool> AuthenticateUserIDWithTouchID()
    {
        var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        var context = new LAContext();
        if (context.CanEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, out NSError AuthError))
        {
            var replyHandler = new LAContextReplyHandler((success, error) => {

                taskSource.SetResult(success);

            });
            context.EvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, "Logging with touch ID", replyHandler);
        };

        return taskSource.Task;
    }
}
```

My question is how do I display the **native prompt** asking if I would like to save to Keychain.

I've created a basic one using xamarin's Display Alert, but it doesn't quite look as nice as the native.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the KeyChain Autofill Save for websites prompt?

Comment: Not quite, I'm referring to iOS apps.

Comment: So am I.. do you have a screen cap of the dialog you are talking about.

Comment: @SushiHangover uploaded.

Comment: You want the alert in your screenshot? Or a native prompt? What does native prompt looks like?